# Can diabetic nerve damage occur even if the blood sugar is under control?

Tags: neurology, diabetes, blood-sugar

Having blood sugar levels elevated at some point of time ago but now kept under control for long, can still cause problems associated with elevated sugar levels?

For instance, diabetic neuropathy?

Comment: Whilst your question about whether symptoms can occur after blood sugar levels are stabilised might work here, you should be aware that personal medical advice is absolutely of-topic for reasons described in [this meta post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/747/how-long-can-this-site-be-popular-if-everybody-is-asked-to-see-a-doctor/748#748). You should also be aware that the symptoms you describe can have various causes other than diabetic neuropathy, and if concerned you should seek further advice/tests to determine the cause from a medical professional near you.

Comment: This could be a reasonable and good question if depersonalized (i.e., if you edit it to take your father out of it). The basic question as I read it could be: "Can diabetic nerve damage appear after blood sugar is brought back under control"

Comment: You have followed the advice given by @DeNovo, so now you need to deal with the issue of prior research. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. This helps to provide an answer which will be more helpful. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: Harshit, For your research, I suggest looking into how long it takes for diabetic neuropathy to develop.